# Problem implementing shufflejs with React

Tags: reactjs, shuffle

Im trying to implement the library [Shufflejs](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/)  together with ReactJS. Im trying to implement the [samplecode for react](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/shuffle-with-react) but when I after installed Shufflejs with `npm install shufflejs` and paisted the code into `index.js` in my React application my page renders blank.

I'm a bit lost why that is. Any help would be appreciated!

the code is here on shufflejs: https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/js/demos/react.js

Comment: Please add examples of your code so others can see how to help - are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: the code is here on shufflejs: https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/js/demos/react.js

Im on a fresh react install. 

No I am not getting any errors so everything seems to work but returns blank. The only error message I dig get was:

"Line 128:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images "

but I fixed that by adding an alt="name" 
after that no errors. just returns as a blank page

Comment: Do you need to import shuffle?

Comment: Hm. Dont think so since I didnt got any error message ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you load Shuffle is not correct here. Replace the import statements with

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Shuffle from 'shufflejs'
```

Comment: thanks. It worked. Is the declaration const "React = window.React;" for when I load it it with cdn?